# Empty HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE Header for Stripe Webhook in local testing

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments, fastapi

I am testing a stripe endpoint and when I try to read the header for HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE, it returns None. Here is my code

```
event = None
    payload = await request.json()
    sig_header = request.headers.get("HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE")
    endpoint_secret = '<secret>'

    print(payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret)

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return ORJSONResponse(
            status_code=response_status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            content=jsonable_encoder({"error": e.user_message})
        )
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return ORJSONResponse(
            status_code=response_status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            content=jsonable_encoder({"error": e.user_message})
        )
```

When I print the sig_header, I get `None` printed. I am not sure why this issue is happening. Does Stripe not send any signature in the header when we are testing locally using cli?

Comment: I have been able to solve the above by replacing `HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE` with `stripe-signature`. However, I am still getting a `stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError`. Not sure why that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you using the correct webhook secret. If you are setting up a local webhook endpoint through Stripe CLI, you can get the webhook secret from the response from `stripe listen`.

Comment: It wasn't a secret issue though. Fixed it using the correct header name for `stripe-signature`